# Probability that the first and fourth balls are red when drawing 4 balls.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Sorry, couldn't fit the entire question into the title.

Question:

> A box contains 15 identical balls except that 10 are red and 5 are
> black. Four balls are drawn successively and without replacement.
> **Calculate the probability that the first and fourth balls are red**.

**My attempt:**

Probability =
$$1*2C0 + 1*2C1 + 1*2C2  \over 4C0 + 4C1 + 4C2 + 4C3 + 4C4 $$

My idea is that no. of ways to make first and fourth balls = 1, and we have 2 balls left which
can either have red or black colors.

**However, my textbook answer was:**

$$10P2*13P2\over15P4$$

Which I don't get at all; why would you use permutations when you have **identical balls**? Wouldn't that mess things up?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always label identical balls to make them distinguishable.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig so my answer would be correct if we don't label them, right?

Comment: If we want a uniform distribution, your answer is not correct.  Your denominator should be the number of ways of selecting four balls from the bag.  Your numerator should be the number of ways of selecting a red ball on the first and fourth draws.

Comment: You can focus on the first and fourth ball. The other two balls are not relevant. As if you place all 15 balls in a row and then wonder: what is the probability that the spots 1 and 4 are filled with a red ball? That is of course the same as the probability that e.g. the spots 1 and 2 (or e.g. 5 and 7) are filled with a red ball.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the probability of first ball and fourth ball being red is same as probability of first and second ball being red.

So desired probability $ = \displaystyle \frac{10}{15} \cdot \frac{9}{14} = \frac{3}{7}$

Answer (score 5):

We can focus solely on the first and fourth draws.  There are $\binom{15}{2}$ ways to select two of the fifteen balls during those draws and $\binom{10}{2}$ ways to select two red balls during those draws.  Hence, the probability that the first and fourth draws are red is
$$\frac{\dbinom{10}{2}}{\dbinom{15}{2}} = \frac{3}{7}$$
which matches the answer in the textbook.

If you wish to account for all four draws, there are four possible sequences: RRRR, RRWR, RWRR, RWWR.  Hence, the probability that red balls are drawn on the first and fourth draws is
$$\frac{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 + 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 5 \cdot 8 + 10 \cdot 5 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 + 10 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 9}{15 \cdot 14 \cdot 13 \cdot 12} = \frac{3}{7}$$

Comment: But aren't we calculating conditional probability that way?

Comment: I added a solution which accounts for selecting all four balls.  The reason we obtain the same answer in either case is that I have accounted for all possible selections of the second and third balls.  The $9 \cdot 8 + 9 \cdot 5 + 5 \cdot 9 + 5 \cdot 4 = 14 \cdot 13 = 182$ ways to do that cancel out, so we only need to focus on the first and fourth draws.  I am not sure why you think the first method is a conditional probability calculation.